# How prevent malformed unicode strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, security, unicode

I was testing some injection attacks on a user text field in my javascript app and found a specific unicode string that causes my other client apps to pretty much crash when they read this value from the database.

How can I prevent these harmful unicode strings while still allowing other unicode like Japanese characters?

For the attack string I used the last option from this document: 
https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt

> 5.3.4  U+nFFFE U+nFFFF (for n = 1..10)                                        |
>                                                                                 |
>          "                                    |
>           "

I read about `encodeURIComponent()` and it sounds like it should throw an error on malformed unicode strings. However, I tried it in a node REPL in my Terminal with the above attack string and it parsed it just fine with no errors. Am I using the encode wrong? Is my Terminal affecting the characters somehow? Should I use a different function?

Any help would be appreciated, I am pretty new to attacks like this.

Comment: String is not harmful. Just that your application is not aware of astral plane of Unicode

Comment: I'm able to display other characters that are in the astral plane such as which is `U+1F600` just not these characters...

Comment: Looks like they are indeed non valid code points (will never be assigned a character) according to https://www.unicode.org/Public/11.0.0/ucd/NamesList.txt. However, many libraries still consider them valid. Perhaps file a bug for them? In the mean time, I guess you would have to add sanitation on server side to remove these characters from the input.

Comment: By the way, encodeURIComponent is not responsible for checking for non-valid code points since they could still be assigned a meaning in private use. It only checks for lone surrogate.